# Проблемы с drag and Drop в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d-ui

Пытаюсь реализовать систему drag & drop в Unity. Но возникла проблемы с тем, что на OnDrag перетаскиваемый объект сильно быстрее мышки в зависимости от разрешения, причём чем оно выше, тем он быстрее.И стандартный метод деления на scaleFactor в canvas не помогает

```
public class DragAndDropQuze : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler
{
   private RectTransform rectTransform;
   private Canvas canvas;
   private void Awake()
   {
    rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    canvas = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
   }
     public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
     {
      Debug.Log("BeginDrag");
    
     }

   public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
  {
    Debug.Log("OnDrag");
    rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta / 
    canvas.scaleFactor;
  }

   public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
   {
      Debug.Log("OnEndDrag");
   }

  public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
  {
      Debug.Log("OnPointerDown");
  }


}
```

Comment: Решить эту проблему можно изменив render mode с World Space на Screen space - Camera ин настроив всё на нужное разрешение. Но такой вариант мне не подходит, буду искать другие варианты решения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно было применить к данным компонентам канваса такие свойства